# Do escape value of hidden input

Tags: php

I have a problem with 'hidden',

PHP:

```
$text = addslashes("Black Sun's zenith");
echo "<input type='hidden' value=".$text." name='saveCard[]'>";
```

showing the actual code is:

```
<input type="hidden" value="Black" sun\'s="" zenith="" name="saveCard[]">
```

to show the correct code is:

```
<input type="hidden" value="Black Sun's zenith" name="saveCard[]">
```

Thank all.

Comment: echo "<input type='hidden' value='{$text}' name='saveCard[]'>";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`addslashes` is a generic routine for escaping content for languages that use the `\` character to start an escape sequence. HTML is not such a language, and most languages that are have a better, more specific function to handle escaping.

Use `htmlspecialchars`, not `addslashes` to escape content for HTML.

Since the attribute value contains spaces, you *also* need to wrap it in quote characters.

```
echo "<input type='hidden' value=\"".htmlspecialchars($text)."\" name='saveCard[]'>";
```

As a rule of thumb, try to avoid putting HTML inside PHP strings.

```
?>
    <input 
        type="hidden"
        value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($text); ?>" 
        name="saveCard[]">
<?php
```

Comment: data not saved to the database. Problem caracters = "Sun's".

Comment: @A.M.Mérida — Probably because something is wrong with the code for taking the submitted data and putting it into the database. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Yes, put `{}` around `$text` variable should help.